# API to scan email?

Tags: web-services, api, rest, language-agnostic

I'm trying to make an app that involves scraping the email of a user to make recommendations. I understand that TripIt does  [this](https://www.tripit.com/uhp/autoImport) but somehow it seems to be too specific to travel. So any links or pointers to a generic API that helps me scan email directly would be helpful(I'm assuming OAuth here).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use OAUTH to authenticate against Gmail:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview

And then use IMAP to get the actual email contents.